# error :- articales.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const articales = {
        title: 'Test Articles',
        createdAt: Date.now(),
        description: "Test Description"
    }
    res.render('index', { articales : articales })
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="mb-4">Blogs</h1>
        <a href="/articales/new" class="btn btn-success">New Article</a>
        <% articales.forEach(article => { %>
            <div class="card mt-4">
                <%= articales.title %>
            </div>
          <% }) %>
    </div>
```

**help me to find the solution**

getting error while running the app.  I can't understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is obvious,you define `articales` as an `Object` rather an `array`,it doesn't support `forEach`

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const articales = {
        title: 'Test Articles',
        createdAt: Date.now(),
        description: "Test Description"
    }
    res.render('index', { articales : articales })
})
```

in order to let it work,you need to define `articales` as an array

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const articales = [{
        title: 'Test Articles',
        createdAt: Date.now(),
        description: "Test Description"
    }]
    res.render('index', { articales : articales })
})
```

Comment: @Shrijit So why not accept my answer?